# Upload data from excel to mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django, excel, save

I am working with django, I receive an excel file through an endpoint to save its data in the database very quickly, as quickly as possible, the excel file has numerical data, it has around 250 columns and 10 thousand rows. I plan to save each measurement in the database with a reference to know which measurements are from which excel. So how can I solve this problem,

I have tried with pandas but it is taking a long time, or what architecture can I implement for this problem?

Comment: Save excel as csv and use load data infile statement to load the data into mysql.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're trying to solve is mostly CPU bound due to the large Excel file to process.
It means that you need to utilise all the CPU cores in order to speed up the data processing.

Here's the approach you can try to solve problem.

Roughly, you need to:

1. Split an Excel file into chunks. The number of chunks should be equal to the number of CPU cores on your machine to evenly distribute the workload.
2. Store the data from each chunk to the database with a single database transaction per chunk within a separate process.

Here's the sample code:

```py
from typing import List

from django.db import transaction
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing

from app.models import Measurement


def split_dataframe(df: pd.DataFrame, num_chunks: int) -> List[pd.DataFrame]:
    """Splits a pandas DataFrame into a list of chunks"""
    chunk_size = int(df.shape[0] / num_chunks) + 1
    return [df[row: row + chunk_size] for row in range(0, df.shape[0], chunk_size)]


@transaction.atomic
def process_chunk(chunk: pd.DataFrame) -> List[Measurement]:
    """Processes a DataFrame chunk"""
    # Convert the chunk to a list of dictionaries
    records = chunk.to_dict("records")

    # Create a list of Measurements from the chunk
    measurements = [Measurement(**record) for record in records]

    # Bulk create the Measurements records in the database
    Measurement.objects.bulk_create(measurements)

    return measurements


def process_excel_file(file_bytes: bytes) -> None:
    """Processes an Excel file using pandas, splitting it into chunks and processing the chunks in parallel"""
    # Read the Excel file into a pandas DataFrame
    # `openpyxl` engine seems to be suitable for reading large Excel files.
    df = pd.read_excel(file_bytes, engine="openpyxl")

    # Get the number of CPU cores on the machine
    num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

    # Split the DataFrame into chunks
    chunks = split_dataframe(df, num_cores)

    # Process the chunks in parallel using multiprocessing
    with multiprocessing.Pool(num_cores) as pool:
        pool.map(process_chunk, chunks)
```